# References on Free Profinite Groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, free-groups, profinite-groups

I would like to study free profinite groups (i.e., [profinite completion](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/profinite+completion+of+a+group#profinite_completion_of_a_group) of free groups) and I am looking for some introductory materials on this topic. Can anyone give me some recommendations?